# Conditional Expectation as a random variable of independent rendom variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

Given two independent random variables $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$, then  $Y=F(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ is a random variable depending on  $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$. 
Would some one help me to detect whether  the two random variables $E[Y|X_1] $ and $E[Y|X_1,X_2]$ are independent or not.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you've made a mistake, since $E(Y/X_1)$ is a number and not a random variable.

Comment: Since $X_1$ is a random variable , then $E[Y/X_1]$  is a random variable depending on $X_1$.

Comment: Oh it is supposed to be a conditioning line. Most literature use a straight line $E(Y | X_1)$, to avoid confusion with division;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have here

$$E[Y|X_1,X_2]=Y=F(X_1,X_2).$$

So your question can be reformulated: "$X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. Are $E[F(X_1,X_2)|X1]$ and $F(X_1,X_2)$ also independent?"

If for instance $F(X_1,X_2)=X_1$ then the question is: "Are $X_1$ and $X_1$ independent?"

Comment: Your discussion is right, thank you, however I edited my post , making the result more general , and at the same time more compatible with my investigation.

Comment: My answer does not really have to be changed: If $Y=X_1$ then the absurd question is the same: "Are $X_1$ and $X_1$ independent?"

Comment: I am not sure, but I think $X_1$ and $X_1$ are dependent

Comment: $P(X_1=a,X_1=b)=0 \text{ or } P(X_1=a)$ if $a=b$. But not $P(X_1=a)P(X_1=b)$ except if $P(X_1=a)=P(X_1=b)=1$ or $0$. Or you are teazing me.